# How many distinct number can I end up with if I keep on multiplying a number with its divisor?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider I've a number 'N' and at every step I multiply it with its divisor 'D' e.g. N := N * D (where D is the divisor of current value of N). I repeat this 'K' times. Is there a way or formula to calculate the number of unique values I can end up with?

Consider when N = 25 and K = 2

For K = 1: 25,125,625

For K = 2: 25,125,625,3125,15625,78125,390625

So overall, I end up with 7 unique values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A number may have more than one divisor. Which $D$ do you choose for $N$?

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni I'm free to choose any D, I'm just concerned with the unique values I end up with. For N = 25 divisors are [1,5,25]. So, for K = 1, I end up with [25,125,625] so three unique values

Comment: Why do you say "$K=2$" and then on next line "For $K=1$"? Why does the line "For $K=1$" includes $2$ multiplications, and the line "For $K=2$" includes $7$?

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni I'm sorry if my question is not clear enough. I was just trying to explain the question a little better. Say N = 25 and K = 2, the unique values I end up with are [25, 125, 625, 3125, 15625, 78125, 390625]

Comment: @Rick I don't understand why you stop at $390625$. This number has $5$ as divisor, like any previous power of $5$ you included, so you could continue: $1953125, 9765625$, etc.

Comment: You would give us a much better idea of your intentions if you used $N=24$ in your examples.

Comment: @Jean-Armand Moroni I've drawn the solution for N = 25 and K = 2. Let me know if this clears things up: https://ibb.co/Wcy868K

Comment: @Rick Oh, OK. Now that's clear, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s start with a number N. Then we pick a divisor D and calculate $N*D$. Then we choose a divisor D’ of ND and calculate $N*D*D’$ and so on, repeating K times.

If N has a prime factor p raised to the power k, then at each step that exponent can be up to doubled; the final result will have the prime factor p raised to a power from k to $k*2^K$, so there are $k*(2^K-1)$ possible exponents.

So to find the number of possibilities, we find all the distinct prime factors of N raised to their highest power k >= 1, multiply each k with 2^K-1, and multiply these products.

For example N=50, K=4: N = $2^1 * 5^2$, 2^K-1 = 15, $(1*15)(2*15) = 450$.

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking around prime factors but was unable to generalize my intuition.